# How to get AMusTCL for theory by self learning?

Tags: theory

Is there any way to get AMusTCL for theory by self study?I can't find any music centre in my area that offers course for Amustcl. Or is there any recommendation for theory classes for AMusTCL in Negeri Sembilan(my area)?Thanks.Maybe I would also consider DipMusLCM?

Comment: Thanks for your posts and advice. I am also planning to self study diploma in theory and was debating on Trinity or LCM. After looking at their sample papers, I think better to go for AMusTCL. I will be sourcing for reading materials.

Comment: Two things here: Number one, you may want to contact the moderators to get your accounts merged. Number two, please don't write "thank you" as an answer.

Comment: How did you go about doing TCL Grade 8 Theory, Elise? (Or anyone who could help answer this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am preparing AMusTCL by self-study. I would advise the following:

1. Comparing the other existing qualifications at the same level (or lower or higher), such as DipMusLCM, AMusLCM and LMusTCL. There is no prerequisite for DipMusLCM. AMusLCM and AMusTCL. One needs to have Grade 8 Theory in Music in order to pursue for LMusTCL, which is higher than AMusTCL.
2. Reading through all the syllabus and the sample papers, which are available for free in the respective websites. Once again, understand thoroughly to see which format of exam is more suitable to your ability. AMusTCL is a single paper of 3 hours, where as AMusLCM consists of two 3-hours papers. I personally feel AMusTCL is better in this sense.
3. AMusTCL requires less essay writing, compared with DipMusLCM or AMusLCM. At least you can choose to answer structural questions in Section B. Good writing skills in English, in the context of music is demanded.
4. Availability of the exam. Will that be difficult for you to find an exam centre to register for the exam? Any local representative? Trinity College London local representative at my area (Penang) is very helpful in advising me the registration process, exam fees and dates, even I will only take in exam in November 2019!
5. Fees! Money is a factor in taking this exam. Which qualification can you afford?
6. How much of time can you allocate to study? Are you a full time student or a busy working adult? Since different syllabus requires certain areas of study, you might roughly calculate the workload that you need in each week and how much of time do you need to spend to study. I am a busy medical personnel working in a hospital with certain days to on-call, and at the same time I am pursuing law degree. Thus, despite I can straight away to sit for LMusTCL with my Grade 8 Theory in Music, but with very limited of time I think AMusTCL suits me better. So, this varies from a person to another.
7. Study materials. DipMusLCM has most of its study materials available free in the website to be downloaded. As I said, most of it, but not completely everything. Past papers can be purchased online and then downloaded and printed. Anna Butterworth's Harmony in Practice is very helpful in tackling Section A. Of course, you can purchase online the Revised 2017 Study Guide AMusTCL which explains the exam well. And you need to buy some scores for Section B.
8. Your previous musical knowledge: If you have learned and sat for Grade 5, 6, 7 and 8 Theory of Music (in this manner, progressively), you probably have gained a good foundation in Harmony. Despite there is not prerequisite for AMusTCL, but I still believe that one must have a Grade 8, or at least its corresponding knowledge in order to study AMusTCL. At the end of the day, it is still a Diploma qualification and definitely much demanding than Grade 8.

Comment: But how about the composing and essay parts?As I believe that these parts needed some marking or advice,so how could you overcome this by self studying?

Answer (score 1):

There's a sample exam paper here.  How close are you to being able to complete it?   The requirements are general musical skills, you don't need a specific AMusTCL course.  I'll have to leave you to research teachers and classes in your area.  But as you've reached the level where you can even consider an advanced diploma, you must have SOME contacts?

http://www.trinitycollege.com/site/?id=1589

Comment: I asked my ABRSM grade 8 theory teacher that she seem even don't know about that there exists some theory diploma.How could I know my answer is correct if there isn't some person to mark my exercise?

Comment: There is a sample answer alongside the sample exam paper.   But, before looking at it, attempt the paper.  Your teacher may not have heard of this diploma.  But she will be able to tell you if your answers are anywhere near the required standard.

Comment: I cannot ask my teacher to help me as I already finished my course with her.

Comment: You're going to have to ask SOME teacher to help you.  Why not the one you already know?    Anyway, talk to her.  If she doesn't want to teach you, she'll be able to recommend someone else.  Teachers LIKE helping ex-students you know!

Comment: Is there any recommendations for anyone who marks papers online?

Comment: Well, is there any recommendations materials for aspects of essay questions? Even though maybe I can do the first section myself(as you said maybe I can ask my teacher for some advice) , the essay question I can't find some materials or any notes in the internet,or is it possible to find out myself by looking the score?

Answer (score 0):

But how about the composing and essay parts?As I believe that these parts needed some marking or advice,so how could you overcome this by self studying? – lyk Feb 15 at 16:20

---

Responding to this question, as long as Trinity does not disclose the marking scheme to the public, no one will know how the marks are allocated for essay or composition, unless you have a teacher who is a Trinity examiner. Trinity website provides the sample paper and suggested answers. From the suggested answers, you may know how extensive and intensive a standard answer should be. Composition and essay are something that really depend on one's creativity and the response could be vary from candidate to candidate, since everyone comes from different background. As far as I concern, DipMusLCM has published a very well written study guide, unfortunately it does not really cover the essay part. I could understand the logic here, LCM (or most of the exam boards) believes there is no standard answer for essay or composition. If you read intensely, you should not have any problem with this. If you do really need guide, you may get an A-Level Music (either Edexcel or Cambridge) textbook to help you.